# Standard audio format using DWT for compression

Tags: audio, dwt, reference-implementation

Is there any standard audio format that employs discrete wavelet transform to compress signals?

Comment: I first was skeptical about the level of research and detail of this question, but then I realized it's not actually easy to find specific information – papers and wikipedia tend to say things like "It is used" or even "wavelet compression is widely employed by..." without actually referring to any actual application. So, this question sparks my interest whether wavelet techniques are used for audio compression. I only know of them in the context of image compression and the (not any more in its hype cycle) applications in orthogonal radio signalling.

Comment: Not that I know of. MP3, Ogg Vorbis, AAC and Opus all use primarily MDCT. Some also use LPC and FFT as well.